# Merge Arrays Combining Matching Objects in Angular Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, merge, angularjs-scope

I have 2 array objects in Angular JS that I wish to merge (overlap/combine) the matching ones.

**For example, the Array 1 is like this:**

```
[
    {"id":1,"name":"Adam"},
    {"id":2,"name":"Smith"},
    {"id":3,"name":"Eve"},
    {"id":4,"name":"Gary"},
]
```

**Array 2 is like this:**

```
[
    {"id":1,"name":"Adam", "checked":true},
    {"id":3,"name":"Eve", "checked":true},
]
```

**I want the resulting array after merging to become this:**

```
[
    {"id":1,"name":"Adam", "checked":true},
    {"id":2,"name":"Smith"},
    {"id":3,"name":"Eve", "checked":true},
    {"id":4,"name":"Gary"},
]
```

Is that possible? I have tried angular's `array_merge` and `array_extend` like this:

```
angular.merge([], $scope.array1, $scope.array2);
angular.extend([], $scope.array1, $scope.array2);
```

But the above method overlap the first 2 objects in array and doesn't merge them based on matching data. Is having a `foreach` loop the only solution for this?

Can someone guide me here please?

Comment: Are/will you use underscore or lodash?

Comment: no. not familar with that and wont be using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this find of merge is supported by AngularJS. I've made a snippet which does exactly the same:

```js
function merge(array1, array2) {
    var ids = [];
    var merge_obj = [];

    array1.map(function(ele) {
        if (!(ids.indexOf(ele.id) > -1)) {
            ids.push(ele.id);
            merge_obj.push(ele);
        }
    });

    array2.map(function(ele) {
     var index = ids.indexOf(ele.id);
        if (!( index > -1)) {
            ids.push(ele.id);
            merge_obj.push(ele);
        }else{
         merge_obj[index] = ele;
        }
    });

    console.log(merge_obj);
}

var array1 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Adam"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Smith"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Eve"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Gary"
}, ]

var array2 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Adam",
    "checked": true
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Eve",
    "checked": true
}, ];

merge(array1, array2);
```

Comment: Thats look very good @AnandSudhanaboina I can use in that in my Angular project and it seems like a good approach. Thank you so much for that. I will give that try now. :)

Comment: Hi @AnandSudhanaboina I tested it in my app and it works well. However, the only thing is it changes the order of the resulting `merge_obj` by placing the matching ones at the top and the rest at the bottom. Is it possible to keep the same order as array 1 was but with the merged data? http://jsfiddle.net/Alien_time/16pd3dd5/

Comment: Updated the answer. If this works do mark as answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thats perfect and it works exactly like I wanted. Thank you so much @AnandSudhanaboina

Answer (score 1):

Genuinely, `extend` in Angular works with object instead of array. But we can do small trick in your case. Here is another solution.

```
// a1, a2 is your arrays
// This is to convert array to object with key is id and value is the array item itself
var a1_ = a1.reduce(function(obj, value) {
    obj[value.id] = value;
    return obj;
}, {});
var a2_ = a2.reduce(function(obj, value) {
    obj[value.id] = value;
    return obj;
}, {});
// Then use extend with those two converted objects
var result = angular.extend([], a1_, a2_).splice(1)
```

**Notes:**

- For compatibility, `reduce` may not work.
- The after array will replace the previous one. This is because of implementation of `extend` in Angular.